# SMS application connection to server using Java ME SDK 3.0

Tags: java-me, wma, java-wireless-toolkit

I am doing a project of developing a mobile payment system.

How can l create an SMS application to send SMS's using Java ME SDK 3.0? I would want the message to be connected to the WAMP server.

Comment: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/smscomposer.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use this free Java sample program to send SMS from your PC using GSM modem connected to your computer to your COM port. You also need to download and install the Java comm api from Sun.

This program needs the following java files to function.

1. SerialConnection.java (This file is used to connect to your COM port from your java program)
2. SerialConnectionException.java (This file is for handling serial connection exceptions in your Java program)
3. SerialParameters.java (This program is used to set your COM port properties for connecting to your com port from your java program)
4. Sender.java (This is the program that implements runnable and sends SMS using the serial connection)
5. SMSClient.java (This java class is the main class that can be instantiated in your own java program and called to send SMS. This program in turn will use all the above four files internally to send out your SMS).

   ```
   public class SMSClient implements Runnable{

   public final static int SYNCHRONOUS=0;
   public final static int ASYNCHRONOUS=1;
   private Thread myThread=null;

   private int mode=-1;
   private String recipient=null;
   private String message=null;

   public int status=-1;
   public long messageNo=-1;


   public SMSClient(int mode) {
     this.mode=mode;
   }

   public int sendMessage (String recipient, String message){
   this.recipient=recipient;
   this.message=message;
   //System.out.println("recipient: " + recipient + " message: " + message);
   myThread = new Thread(this);
   myThread.start();
   //    run();
   return status;
   }
   public void run(){

   Sender aSender = new Sender(recipient,message);

   try{
     //send message
         aSender.send ();

        // System.out.println("sending ... ");

     //in SYNCHRONOUS mode wait for return : 0 for OK,
     //-2 for timeout, -1 for other errors
     if (mode==SYNCHRONOUS) {
         while (aSender.status == -1){
           myThread.sleep (1000);
         }
     }
     if (aSender.status == 0) messageNo=aSender.messageNo ;

   }catch (Exception e){

       e.printStackTrace();

   }

   this.status=aSender.status ;

   aSender=null;
   ```

   }
   }